# Swift - Open Google Maps with URL

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to launch Google Maps from within my app with a specific URL (show location of someone). Nonetheless, as a first step, I am trying to work with the Google Maps iOS API sample code, but I am getting an error.

Here is my function:

```
@IBAction func goToHomeAddressPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        /*Get Coordinates From User Object*/
        if(self.userObject.homeAddress[0] != "" && self.userObject.homeAddress[1] != "")
        {
            let lat: String = self.userObject.homeAddress[0]
            let lon: String = self.userObject.homeAddress[1]

            print("Address: \(self.userObject.homeAddress[0]) and \(self.userObject.homeAddress[1])")

                if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
            } else {
                print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
            }
        }else{
            print("Problem opening Google Maps with specified address")
        }


    }
```

The address coordinates are not null and they print to console. But I get this error message:

> ```
> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "(null)"
> Can't use comgooglemaps://
> ```

I read in another Stackoverflow thread, that I must have values inserted into info.plist. I have these by default:

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me what's going on.

Thanks,

Comment: Just confirming, do you have Google maps app installed ?

Comment: @san On the simulator iPhone? No...should I ?

Comment: Yes, you should test this on device(iPhone/iPod/iPad) and that device should have Google maps app installed. Since your device does not have this app installed so it is failing

Comment: @san oh ok. Allow me sometime to test it on a real device and then k can mark your response as answer. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

If you only have to open up a location in google map may be you should try using something like this 
https://maps.google.com/?q=@37.3161,-122.1836

This will open up google maps with the co-ordinates provided in the url, if google maps is not installed on the device it will open up safari will the same url.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme for google url scheme

Answer (score 1):

```
  let lat = self.upcomingListArr[indexPath.item].latitude!
            let long = self.upcomingListArr[indexPath.item].longitude!
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL)) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(String(describing: lat)),\(String(describing: long))")! as URL)

            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(String(describing: lat)),\(String(describing: long))")! as URL)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, you may not have Google maps app installed. Please test your code on a device(iPhone/iPod/iPad) and that device should have Google maps app installed. Since your device does not have Google maps app installed so it is failing